# Angular Form persistence: restore Form after the component was destroyed

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm usig `FormBuilder` to have a simple form in my **Angular 5.1.2** project:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  const formSettings = {
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50), this.nameValidator]],
    deviceType: ['', [Validators.required]],
    description: ['']
  };
  this.newDeviceForm = this.formBuilder.group(formSettings);
}
```

And the Form's template looks like:

```
<form [formGroup]="newDeviceForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="name" name="name">
    <mat-error *ngIf="newDeviceForm.get('name').hasError('required')">
      Device Name is required
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="newDeviceForm.get('name').hasError('maxlength')">
      Device Name should be no more than 50 characters
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <!-- ... -->
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="description" name="description">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I want to implement a mechanism of Form persistence to satisfy following user story:

1. User started working with Form.
2. He made some field invalid and saw validation message.
3. Then he went out to another page, Form had been destroyed.
4. Then he returned to the Form page.
5. Form restored, User saw his dirty field with validation message from p.2.

I tried to persist the Form via global service in a way like:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  if(this.devicesService.newDeviceForm) { // form caching
    this.newDeviceForm = this.devicesService.newDeviceForm;
    return;
  }
  const formSettings = { /* ... */ };
  this.newDeviceForm = this.formBuilder.group(formSettings);
  this.devicesService.registerForm(this.newDeviceForm); // populate DevicesService.newDeviceForm
}
```

But it does not work. Is there some approach that could allow to persist whole the Form and make it reusable with all its specific properties?

Comment: are you using ngModel on the inputs for the form?

Comment: @Zachscs No. I updated the question.

Comment: In your last code block, which bit does not work, i.e do you have a value returned from the service but the form is not rehydrating, or is the service not retaining the form info? Will help focus on service or forms.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine there, it looks that is a problem with the reference, have you tried to use ` this.devicesService.registerForm(Object.assign({}, this.newDeviceForm));` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the reference to the `this.newDeviceForm`
Here you have a demo using the case that you provided, I have simplified the service class.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjyjco

```js
class DeviceService {
  private _deviceForm: FormGroup = null;

  constructor() {}

  registerForm(form: FormGroup): void {
    this._deviceForm = form;
  }

  restoreForm(): FormGroup {
    return this._deviceForm;
  }
}

class NewDeviceComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public newDeviceForm: FormGroup = null;

  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public deviceService: DeviceService) {}

  ngOnInit() {    
    if (this.deviceService.restoreForm() != null) {
      this.newDeviceForm = this.deviceService.restoreForm();
    } else {
      const formSettings = {
        name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
        deviceType: ['', [Validators.required]],
        description: ['']
      };
      this.newDeviceForm = this.formBuilder.group(formSettings);  
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.deviceService.registerForm(Object.assign(new FormGroup({}), this.newDeviceForm));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the demo! Investigating it I realized that I was resetting the Form while leaving the Form component... So, the approach works in general. I also added some code from your demo to your answer, this could be useful for the Community.

Comment: You are welcome. And thanks for the edit, that added a lot of value to the answer.